# Sequelize query matches requirements for $LIKE but receives ER_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database, sequelize.js

I have a table called MedicalStaff, and an array of doctor's email addresses that I can use to query MedicalStaff. I want to use findAll to find any matches with this array, and it looks like the $like : {$any: [array] }} operator described halfway down the page [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/) is the best method for doing this.

I have the following query:

```
var address = ['BubGuy@mailinator.com', 'DumbTime@mailinator.com'];
sequelizeInstance.models.MedicalStaff.findAll({where: {email: {$like: { $any: address}}}})
    .then(function(doctors){
        console.log(doctors);
        ...
     }
```

and get the following error:

```
{ SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near '('BubGuy@mailinator.com','DumbTime@mailinator.com')' at line 1  
...
 code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
 errno: 1064,
 sqlState: '42000',
 index: 0,
 sql: 'SELECT `name`, `email`, `password`, `salt`, `phoneNumber`, `position`, 
`authenticationCode`, `active`, `unassigned`, `resetPasswordToken`, 
`isVerified`, `resetPasswordExpires`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `fk_id`, `fk_email` 
FROM `MedicalStaffs` AS `MedicalStaff` WHERE `MedicalStaff`.`email` 
LIKE ANY (\'BubGuy@mailinator.com\',\'DumbTime@mailinator.com\');' },
```

It's indicating a parse error (1064) but I'm not sure why, since address is well-defined and I'm following the documentation in the link exactly as they use it. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to use '%%' in like parameter?

Comment: That's not required per the Sequelize documentation for $like: {$any: [ ]}} in the linked querying documentation.

Comment: `like` operator without wildcards is pointless. What you want is a simple `in()`.

Comment: @Shadow is right, $in was what I wanted all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out mysql documentation on [any subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) and it says:

> Syntax:
>
> operand comparison_operator ANY (subquery) operand IN (subquery)
>   operand comparison_operator SOME (subquery) Where comparison_operator
>   is one of these operators:
>
> =  >  <  >=  <=  <>  !=

The list of operators do not even include the `like` operator. Using the `like` operator without wildcards is a bit pointless because then they are very similar to a simple `=` (not the same though).

I would say you need the `in()` operator (`$in`) to compare a string against a list of strings.